# .htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache, httpd.conf

I uploaded the .htaccess to the server and received an **Error 500 (Internal Server Error)**.

And in the error log I had the following error:

**.../.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here**

But `mod_rewrite.so` is enabled.

So, do I need to change

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

in the **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** file?

Or could it be something else? The .htaccess file should be okay, because it works perfectly fine on my localhost. I just don't want to screw anything up.

Here's part of my .htaccess file:

```
Options All -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Yes, it's all about `AllowOverride` directive. Not necessary `AllowOverride All` .. but at least `AllowOverride FileInfo`. Details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: is that's all the error log shows?

Comment: @linuxeasy Yes. The path and .htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here. That's it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

minimum configuration for your .htaccess to work:

```
AllowOverride FileInfo Options
```

allowing all configuration will work as well:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: AllowOverride All wroked but AllowOverride FileInfo Options doesn't, wp-includes/.htaccess: deny not allowed here

Comment: @Jacek Kaniuk How to allow htaccess in 1and1

Comment: `AllowOverride` controls the _type_ of directives that can be used in `.htaccess`. So whether `AllowOverride FileInfo Options` is sufficient is entirely dependent on what directives you are using. `FileInfo` is required for mod_rewrite, `FileInfo Options` is required for the `.htaccess` file in the question. To use `Deny` in `.htaccess` you also need to include the `Limit` directive-type. @Sérgio But most just stick with `All` for "ease of use".

Comment: However, contrary to what this answer implies, you should never set anything other than `AllowOverride None` in the `<Directory />` container (as stated in the question) - which refers to the _server root_ - the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) specifically warn against doing this "for security and performance reasons". Instead, this should be set for the specific directory that contains the `.htaccess` file, such as the DOCUMENT_ROOT, as mentioned in @anubhava's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Let's say your DOCUMENT_ROOT is `/home/foo/web` then have this config in your httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "/home/foo/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This should take care of `RewriteEngine is not allowed` error you're getting.

Answer (score 4):

Just an idea, this happened to me, and I've lost a lot of time trying to solve it.

If you have a directory like `d:/web/my-sites/some-site/`

And you place the `.htaccess` on `d:/web/my-sites/some-site/.htaccess` (where it supposed to be).

If you have ANY `.htaccess` files before this directory, Apache reads that files, and blocks the execution of the entire path, producing an internal server error.

I.E.: You have `d:/web/my-sites/.htaccess`

Comment: I just found a solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084190/rewriteengine-not-allowed-here-caused-by-htaccess-in-parent-directory

Comment: This should still depends on how/where you have `AllowOverride` (and `AllowOverrideList` on Apache 2.4+) set. And possibly the Apache version, since the default value of the `AllowOverride` directive changed between Apache 2.2 and 2.4.

Answer (score 3):

In httpd version 2.4 (2.4.3 and 2.4.4), take a look at /etc/httpd/conf.d/wordpress.conf
There is one entry for:

....

Change:
"AllowOverride Options"
to 
"AllowOverride All"

in wordpress.conf also in addition to changing httpd.conf. Restart the http server before the changes will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change username.conf file on Mac under `/etc/apache2/users/username.conf` to

```
<Directory "/Users/akyoo/Sites/">
   AllowOverride All
   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My `.htaccess` file looks like this

```
#Allow from all
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works fine for me.
 [Solution for Ubuntu users](http://www.binarytides.com/fix-htaccess-options-not-allowed-here-error/)

Comment: Just to add, only enable `MultiViews` if you specifically need it. If you are using mod_rewrite, as in this example, then you probably don't - and this can potentially result in unexpected conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Also, just make sure you are editing the correct config file.  I had created a file under /etc/apache2/users/USERNAME.conf but was editing /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.

Removing the USERNAME.conf file worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this type of error from the Google Cloud instance after checking the logs from the  `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

> .htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here

To get rid of the above error & 500 Internal Server Error, follow these simple steps

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add these snippets of lines

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After you’ve made that change, make sure to restart the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This worked for me in getting rid of 500 Internal Server Error hosted on Google Cloud instance

Answer (score -4):

you could use something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|html|test)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

this code simply means, that anything not pointing to index.php or html or test should be directed to index.php!

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Oh, I think I will use that thanks! But I don't think that gets rid of the problem that RewriteEngine is not allowed.