# WordPress in subdirectory of subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

This should be simple - can't figure out where I'm going wrong:

We have WordPress installed in the following location: http://example.com/gallery/cms
and I want the site to be visible at http://example.com/gallery

I have the WordPress Address set to http://example.com/gallery/cms and the Site Address set to http://example.com/gallery

I copied the .htaccess and index.php to the /gallery folder. The .htaccess contains the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gallery/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /gallery/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The index.php contains the following code:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require('./cms/wp-blog-header.php');
```

The home page loads up fine, but any interior pages kick of a "Not Found" error: `http://playstartshere.com/gallery/specs/` yields `The requested URL /gallery/specs/ was not found on this server.`

Where am I going wrong? I tried changing index.php to:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require('./gallery/cms/wp-blog-header.php');
```

but that broke the site entirely.

**EDIT: ANSWER**

Apache was indeed incorrectly configured; RewriteEngine was not enabled. However, the .htaccess was also wrong. Correct .htaccess for a configuration like what's above is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gallery/cms/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /gallery/cms/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/gallery/specs/` is matched by this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

which block access

Try `/gallery/.htaccess` with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

without `/` prepending index.php, apache will search in current directory

***edit***

Once again with different approach:

set all wordpress URLs to http://example.com/gallery
put all wordpress files in /gallery/cms

put one .htaccess in /gallery/cms

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

put second .htaccess in /gallery (without index.php)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/gallery/cms
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gallery/cms/$1 [L]
```

Comment: So I replaced the entire .htaccess with the following:  

`RewriteEngine On`  
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`  
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`  
`RewriteRule . index.php [L]`  
  
No joy - I still get the 404 Not Found error :(

Comment: but where did You put that .htaccess?

Comment: Thanks again for the response! So I did the following:
1) Updated the .htaccess in both /gallery/cms and /gallery to be the code you indicated 2) removed the index.php from /gallery. The result was that it simply showed the directory listing of files inside the /gallery folder. I then put the index.php file back in; same problem as before: the home page shows fine but navigating to any of the interior pages brings up a 404 error. Any other ideas?

Comment: SOA#1, maybe Apache is badly configured: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995545/htaccess-rewriteengine-not-allowed-here#answer-6997903