# How to hide php extension using a .htaccess and still keep the path_info superglobal accessible

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wonder what is the correct way to hide php extension from urls when using a .htaccess. Currently I have my .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php     -f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)$/(.+)$/(.+)$/$   /$1.php/$2/$3 [S]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php     -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$          /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

The above second rule is because I have to keep the PHP_INFO accessible when giving a url like this: xxx/vision.php/2013/Enero

And in the htdocs directory I have AllowOverridde Options and it is set up like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
```

But it's giving me an Internal Server Error whenever I try to access the server document root. 
Perhaps someone is able to point me in the right direction, and hopefully soon cause I'm in a hurry

Comment: Look into the webservers `error.log` to find out. Also `$` is the subject end marker, and thus unlikely to be useful more than once in your second rule.

Comment: @mario So I suppose I could write the second rule like this  RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)$/(.+)/(.+)/   /$1.php/$2/$3 [S]. However the error log tells me that Rewrite Engine AND RewriteCond is not allowed in my .htaccess! I've tried several combinations, putting the whole Conditions and Rules in the .htaccess, or setting the RewriteEngine and RewriteBase in the httpd.config, but none have worked so far.

Comment: It seems to reject every possible tweak I make. From the error log I get either "RewriteEngine not allowed here" (in the path to my .htaccess) or "RewriteCond not allowed here". I don't get it, ¿what am I missing?

Comment: I changed the httpd.config so that the section reading: `<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>` now reads `Allow from all` but it doesn't work either

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995545/htaccess-rewriteengine-not-allowed-here)

Comment: Thanks @mario for the link to your answer. The problem was I had `AllowOverride Options`, where I needed to have `AllowOverride All` in httpd.config

Answer (score 0):

```
Options MultiViews
```

will do it without mod_rewrite. MultiViews lets you reach files without their extension. And because `AcceptPathInfo` is On by default for .php and other script files, this will work too:

```
/abc/articles/2013/Enero
```

will go to /abc/articles.php, giving it the PATH_INFO of `/2013/Enero`.