# Apache upgrade 2.2 -> 2.4 issue

Tags: apache

I have got a problem with an update of Apache (from 2.2 to 2.4). I keep getting the same message while trying to access 'localhost'

> .htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here

Also the result that I get from browser is 500 Internal Server Error.

I have completely change old authorization tags from Allow from all to Require all granted, still the same. Tried to load mod_access_compat - still the same.

Any ideas? My httpd.conf is almost a default one at the moment, the only changes are DocumentRoot and Directory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995545/htaccess-rewriteengine-not-allowed-here

Comment: I have got 'AllowOverride All', still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confused while editing my old httpd.conf - it had configured DocumentRoot as follows:

```
DocumentRoot "web/"

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "web/">
...
```

With this configuration, new Apache would not like to work. I changed Directory to "/" and it worked.

It is also neccessary to load mod_rewrite module and setup AllowOverride to All (or FileInfo).