# Redirect any URL starting with some characters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect something like:

```
domain/start[optional]/xxx
```

to

```
domain/something/xxx
```

I've tried to add to `.htaccess`:

```
# Rewrite any start* route to something route
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^start[^/]*/(.*)$ /something/$1 [R=301, L]
```

but I'm getting an Internal Server Error. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

The Apache logs says:

> RewriteCond: bad argument line '%{REQUEST_URI}'

Comment: what does the internal server error say?

Comment: your rewriterules seems correct, you probably get the error because you have to allow overrides in htaccess. in that case, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995545/htaccess-rewriteengine-not-allowed-here

Comment: @TZHX - Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule has few syntax issues. Try this rule:

```
# Rewrite any start* route to something route
RewriteRule ^start[^/]*/(.*)$ /something/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Great! You're always solving my regex issues :)

Comment: Now, I'm not getting the server error any more, but doesn't redirect. Let me try some stuff before marking as answered.

Comment: Is `start` a directory? If not then place this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line

Comment: In my own example, `something` is `startsomething`, so I'm getting infinite redirections. How could I avoid it? I mean, do the redirect just once.

Comment: For that you can tweak regex to: **`RewriteRule ^start(?!something)[^/]*/(.*)$ /something/$1 [R=301,L,NC]`**