# Ubuntu 16.04 + Apache2 - .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2.4

I have small problem with Apache2 + Ubuntu 16.04, after install php, mysql ant other stuff, I can't go to subpage's by pretty URL.

All pages are in subfolder /var/www/html/:

- sub1
- sub2
- sub3

> URL: 192.168.1.23/sub1 - work
>
> URL: 192.168.1.23/sub1/public/index.html - work
>
> URL: 192.168.1.23/sub/c/product-name-123 - don't work, 404 error: The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

I made a lot of changes in 000-default.conf, apache2.conf but they dosen't work

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_log ./logs/error.log
```

Comment: Is that htaccess file being read? Try adding gibberish to it.

Try also LogLevel rewrite:trace8

Comment: Did you set `AllowOverride None`?  if so it's not going to work and check out  [.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995545/htaccess-rewriteengine-not-allowed-here)